# How to let AJAX read python render variable to HTML?

Tags: java, python, html, django

PLEASE HELP (T_T), I'm a new django learner.

My question is how do I write Ajax to load my {{channel_mlx90614}} that I render from views.py ?
I wanted to create a button to refresh the data from python, So I render the data from Views.py in Django, which is {{channel_mlx90614}}, but I wanted to button click refresh the data value when my firebase database data is changed, which in asynchronous way instead of refreshing the browser.

```
**view.py**
    
        firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
        db = firebase.database()
        
        def index(request):
            channel_mlx90614 = db.child('mlx90614').child('1-set').child('ambient').get().val()
            if channel_mlx90614 >= 37.5:
                temperature_note = "High Temperature alert !"
            elif channel_mlx90614 <= 37.5:
                temperature_note = "Normal Temperature !"
            else:
                temperature_note = "No temperature detected !"
            return render(request, 'mysite1/index.html', {
                "channel_mlx90614":channel_mlx90614,
                "temperature_note":temperature_note
            })
    
     **sample.html**
        
        <button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
        
        <p id="demo"></p>
        
        <script>
        document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);
        
        function displayDate() {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "{{channel_mlx90614}}";
        }
        
        <script language="javascript">
        $(function(){
          $(".myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#demo").load( ????? ); 
    
    // How to read {{channel_mlx90614}} render from python to html?
          });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: You have to make a AJAX GET request to the url ```index``` and get the response (channel_mlx90614 and temperature_note). After you get the response you can load that data in your template.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any example?

Comment: You can check [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-ajax-request-in-django/amp/) out